# ipBest Practice IPhone Interface Design

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display a long list of controls that go off screen?  If you have played or seen IMobsters, it's kind of like the missions tab. There are 15 jobs, each job "section" would have 4 labels, 2 buttons, and an image. I want some static info at the top, then be able to scroll through all the jobs.

Also, do you ever run into a "Feasibility" limit for how many controls you have to code and connect using IB? There would over 200 different labels and controls here I would have to make IVARS etc. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `UITableView` for your purpose. Each cell will correspond to job 'section' you described and will contain 4 labels, 2 buttons, and an image (or whateve you want). `UITableView` will handle scrolling your contents if it is too large, proper reusing of its cells will also allow you to avoid creating >200 instances of UI elements and will improve your app performance and memory usage.

Comment: I knew these many hour of playing with UIScrollView was a goose chase. I did finally get all my controls to scroll, but you couldn't go to the end, and while scrolled, it wouldn't let you click on the buttons until it snapped back into place.  Table View! That's what I need to research.  Thank you so much!